# Запланированные действия для телеграм бота с использованием pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule, telebot

Суть моей задачи состоит в следующем:
Я хочу, что бы раз в неделю (в суботу) флажок четности недели менялся с 0 на 1 и наоборот, поскольку от этого зависят ответы бота.

Я пытался использовать библиотеку schedule, но для запуска планированных действий нужны следующие строки кода:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Таким образом метод `bot.polling()`, который находится чуть ниже не может выполняться.

Если же эти 2 кусочка кода свапнуть, то тогда все хэндлеры будут работать отлично, но запланированное действия не будет выполняться.

Возможно, если Вы подскажете, есть и другие способы реализовать задачу описанную в первом предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Проще и надёжнее не хранить флажок, а вычислять его каждый раз от текущей даты.

Выбираете один конкретный день в прошлом, который принимается за точку отсчёта.
А потом каждый раз, когда нужно узнать флажок делаете так:

```
from datetime import datetime


# Какая-то суббота в прошлом
# которую мы приняли за точку отсчёта
zero_point = datetime(2020, 1, 4)


def week_flag():
    now = datetime.now()
    days_past = (now - zero_point).days
    week_num = (days_past // 7) + 1
    flag = week_num % 2
    return flag


print(week_flag())
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать модуль threads. В отдельный файл, я назвал его swapper.py, вынесите этот код:

```
from threads import Threads
from datetime import datetime as dt
flag=0
dates=[]
def swap():
    global flag, dates
    while True:
        now_date = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0]
        if( (datetime.weekday()==5) and (now_date not in dates)):
            if flag==0: flag=1; dates.append(now_date)
            elif flag==1: flag=0; dates.append(now_date)
thread1 = Thread(target=swap)
thread1.start()
```

А в главный файл напишите это:

```
from threads import Threads
import swapper
Код вашего бота
swapper.thread1.join()
```

чтобы узнать значение переменной нужно написать следующее: `swapper.flag`